# how to check if date1 is smaller date2 and assign value in new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I want to compare 2 dates (Shipment Dt and theoretical ship date) in a dataframe and assign value "1" if Shipment date is before/on theoretical ship date and value "0" if Shipment Dt date is after  theoretical ship date. I want to store the new value in a column called 'on time'

'''

```
Shipment Dt Creation date   Lead time   theoretical ship date
0   2020-01-02  2019-12-31  20  2020-01-28
1   2020-02-03  2019-12-27  30  2020-02-07
2   2020-04-03  2020-04-01  20  2020-04-29
3   2020-04-06  2020-04-01  30  2020-05-13
4   2020-04-07  2020-04-01  20  2020-04-29

dataTypeSeries = df.dtypes
print(dataTypeSeries)

Shipment Dt              datetime64[ns]
Creation date            datetime64[ns]
Lead time                         int64
theoretical ship date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

'''
I tried

```
df['on time'] = df['theoretical ship date'].apply(lambda x: '1' if x <= x['Shipment Dt'] else '0')
```

But I get error
`'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable`'

Second question is whether there is a way to do it without adding a column for theoretical ship date ---> if shipment date is smaller or equal to creation date plus lead time (in days) assign 1 else 0.

Comment: have another look at what a `lambda` function does. here, it will iterate over the column, so `x['Shipment Dt']` throws an error since x is a timestamp from `df['theoretical ship date']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a boolean mask and convert it to `int` to get a column of ones and zeros depending on if your condition is met:

```
df['on time'] = (df['Shipment Dt'] <= df['theoretical ship date']).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this easily.make sure dates are properly converted to datetime

```
df["Shipment Dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Shipment Dt"])
df["theoretical ship date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["theoretical ship date"])
df['on time'] = (df['Shipment Dt'] <= df['theoretical ship date']).astype(int)
```

if you want to use lambda,use axis=1 to consider dataframe in axis 1.

```
df['on time'] = df.apply(lambda x: int(x['Shipment Dt']<=x['theoretical ship date']),axis=1)
```

Comment: since the error says `'Timestamp' object is not subscriptable` I believe conversion to datetime was already successfully done.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @Rajith Thennakoon and @MrFuppes I was able to code it as below without adding a column for 'theoretical shipdate'

```
temp = df['Lead time'].apply(np.ceil).apply(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x, unit='D'))
df['on time'] = (df['Shipment Dt'] <= (df['Creation date']+temp)).astype(int)
```

Comment: I think that here also there is a solution without using `apply` and/or `lambda` :) while it is fine to use those with small datasets, they can be slowing down the processing of large datasets due to the iteration.